# How can I include nested Parse objects when passing results from a query to a template?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm using Parse JavaScript SDK to build a web app but I can't get past the following issue. I need to pass results from a query to a collection that in turn gets passed to my template (using underscore) but I can't get my template to display any data that comes from a nested Parse object inside the top level objects from the collection.

This is how I get the results from Parse and into my template:

```
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    documents.add(results);
    var documentsView = new app.documentsView({collection: documents});
    $("#main-content").html(documentsView.render().el);
  }
}
```

This is the line I can't get to work inside my template:

```
    <td><%= proveedor["rut"] %></td>
```

Here, `proveedor` is the nested Parse object and `rut` is a property of said object.

Nothing is shown in this line of my template as result.

What I have gathered so far is that `documents.add(results)` adds it as JSON but with pointers where the nested objects should be. Any idea how to pass the full object?

Any help with this will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Parse query returns JSON object with root=results. Just feed 'results' to your template and traverse the json normally per json traversal syntax ... examples .. items="[[response.results]]" as="item" .... <span class="asked">[[ item.requestedBy.0.username ]]</span> ... <span class="line">[[item.requestedRole.name]]</span>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can get it to work with every attribute that is a value of the objects contained in `results`. The problem I'm having is accesing the attributes of an object that is itself an attribute of an object in `results`. When I get to the second level deep I get a pointer instead of the full object. Any idea how to get the full object?

Comment: Just to clarify, in my query I have `query.include("proveedor")` and when I log the results I do have all the data I need. But when passing it to my template I loose the data from the second level.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I got it to work was doing this in my template:

```
<td><%= this.model.attributes.proveedor.attributes.rut %></td>
```

Any idea why this work but `<td><%= proveedor.rut %></td>` doesn't?